# Why won't my R object print to file?

Tags: r, file-io

I have been struggling to make my R program print to a file. I have tried write, write.table, writeLines and cat but all to no avail, and I was hoping that someone could tell me where I am going wrong here. 
Here is one attempt:

```
cat(searchn, file = "output.txt", sep = " ")
```

And here is another:

```
write.table(searchn, file = "output.txt", row.names = FALSE,
            append = FALSE, col.names = TRUE, sep = " ")
```

But they all just end up with empty files. I know that searchn has an actual value though:

```
head(searchn)
factor(0)
1253 Levels: 1:12 1:56 ... X:93
```

Because of the fact the searchn has data in it, I am inclined to think that it is just a problem in my line of code that attempts to write to the file. Although I don't know what factor(0) means and a quick google search didn't turn much up. I would welcome an explanation on that front even if it is not causing my troubles. 
Does anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: what do `str(searchn)` and `dput(searchn)` return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your object `searchn` contains no values. I know that because the result of `head(searchn)` is:

```
factor(0)
```

which means you have a `factor` of length zero, i.e. it's empty.

Although the object is empty, it still contains meta-information about the factor levels, for example.  So printing this meta-information should work without a problem. For example, try:

```
cat(levels(searchn), file="output.txt")
```

Comment: Ah, you are quite right. If I were to give you some more of my code could you tell me how it happened that searchn had no value? I am trying to understand the tricky bits of R.

Comment: @User, yes, but probably it's best to post a new question.  And before you do, use copious amounts of `head(x)` or `str(x)` to trace the point where it occurs.